# Is it possible to have a variable accessible and modified by different functions of the same class in PHP?

Tags: php

I declare a variable as private in the body of the class and set it to null. After that, I access the variable by a function in the class and initialize it. When I try to read the value of this variable from another function, it's always null! Did I miss something?

Comment: Please post your class definition.  The property declared as private should hold its value until it is GC'ed at the end of the request.

Comment: I don't know but I could tell you if show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ooooo I did a big mistake. I was accessing the variables like that

```
$variable
```

instead of

```
$this->variable
```

Comment: I think you will never forget it again :)